# Respond add header PDF C# cannot open file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf, adobe

I have some problem about respond add header Generate to PDF.
when load PDF It cannot open file.
What should I do. I am the beginner of WEB developer.

[image]

when I click Open file. Adobe alert me as image.
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the `ActionResult View()` indeed is a PDF?

Comment: Yes if i change content type to Excel. i generate Excel file it's not a problem
but PDF it does not work.

Comment: I doubt that. Excel most likely merely is nice enough to open different formats claiming being Excel files.

Comment: Simply store the data you retrieve from that URL and inspect it to verify its format. If you don't know how to verify, share the data to allow us to inspect.

Comment: When you change to Excel, do you perhaps save it to ".xls"? If you are I should point out that this is a "trick", you see your output file is of HTML format, but MS Excel will be able to notice that and open it if it's named with ".xls" extension. However, this will not work for PDF, because Adobe Reader doesn't understand HTML. In other words, you're not generating Excel nor PDF file, you're simply outputing your HTML as files with different extensions.

Comment: You are not actually generating a pdf in response, you are returning HTML instead pdf that is why the message is shown, you have to return FileResult containing the actual pdf file